# Expressing acceleration in terms of velocity and derivative of velocity with respect to position

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation, calculus

we know that

$$a = \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

dividing numerator and denominator by $dx$, we get $$a=v\dfrac{dv}{dx}$$ provided that $dx$ is not equal to zero or instantaneous velocity not equal to zero

when I questioned my teacher that this formula implies instantaneous velocity should not be zero or their should be no turnaround points then why we use this formula for deriving equations of particle's position , velocity which is performing SHM, but got no satisfactory answer.

what is wrong in my argument and what are the conditions under which above mentioned equation is not true?

Comment: so if we have v=dx/dt and by your saying that dx is not equal to zero , dt not equal to zero then v=dx/dt can never be zero which os completely wrong where is the flaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is assuming that dv/dx is finite when v=0. Try this for motion with uniform acceleration.  For example,  for object thrown upwards with some initial velocity.  At the top turning point the expression fir dv/dx tends to infinity.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write all math.

Comment: so why do we use this equation in such cases

Comment: @lalittolani Who is we?

Comment: @lalittolani i dont think we use the a = v dv/dx equation

Comment: hmm i think coorect equation is a/v=dv/dx

Comment: and therefore we can bring v to RHS provided when it is not equal to zero

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the equation.  It is just your interpretation, for the special case of a turning point, which is flawed.